# Can't get this java code to run faster

Tags: java, performance, readline

I'm participating in an online judge page, where I solved a problem, but I just can't make my program run in time. The code is as follows:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
Set l = new HashSet();
String line;
String[] numStr;
 while(true){
  line = in.readLine();      
  numStr = line.split("\\s");      
  int a = Integer.parseInt(numStr[0]);
  if(a == 0){
     System.exit(0);
  }
  int n = 0;
  int b = Integer.parseInt(numStr[1]);
  l.clear();
  for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
    l.add(in.readLine());
  }
  for(int i=0;i<b;i++){
    if(l.contains(in.readLine())){
      n++;
    }
  }
  System.out.println(n);
```

I came to a point where for a test case of 2 million items (numStr = "1000000 1000000") I got it to run under 1.5s, but apparently that's not enough for the test cases (it says 3000ms). And now I don't know how can I make it faster, any help is greatly appreciated!

Problem: http://coj.uci.cu/24h/problem.xhtml?abb=1438

Comment: Note that 1.5s is 1500ms. I checked the website to make sure we're on the same page, and yeah, you're twice as fast as you need to be.

Comment: What do you mean by "fast enough"?  Who/what is suggesting that 1.5s is too slow?  That seems pretty reasonable to me.

Comment: Yeah, I know it *should* be fast enough, but it is not. I fail because of "Time Limit Exceeded": http://coj.uci.cu/24h/status.xhtml?abb=1438 (my username is Kirby).

Comment: maybe your `if(a == 0)` condition is not getting fired, so your program is still waiting for input but there is none and the evaluator marks it as time limit exceeded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "in increasing order" part of the input specification is the key: since both lists are pre-sorted, you can read the first one into an array, and then use binary search from the location of the last item to the end of the array to decide if you have a match or not. In fact, even a linear search of the first array might work, because you will need to traverse it at most once.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't realize this. Thank you very much, I owe you a cookie!

Comment: A "merge" will be faster in most cases.

Comment: @BruceMartin If you go linearly, you'll end up with the run time of merge. If you use binary search, you will go faster when the two sets of numbers are dissimilar; it will degenerate to linear when the two lists are identical.

Comment: With both cases most of the time will be spent on IO. If you consider the case where both 
have around list have a 1000000 entries; the Merge will do 1000000 * 2 comparisons; the binary
search will do around 1000000 * 20 comparisons. The binary search will do beter when the 
Binary-search list is very large and ther second list is very small.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the first input line were `1000000 0`; your program would read the million values and enter them into the hash, only to have no values to look up, so that the output is guaranteed to be 0.  This would clearly take a lot longer than necessary (you need to read them, but not store them in the hash).

Also, you only check the first value being 0 to terminate; by the spec, `0 1000000` should produce an output of 0, but you program would terminate.  Maybe the judge isn't checking for this, but it would be legitimate for it to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Because the data is sorted, it is well suited to Merge processing

i.e The logic to process is

```
Read Jacks records into array

While (More of jacks record to process)
  and (More of Jills record to process)  {

      if ( jacks_Record < Jills_Record)
         Jacks_Array_Index += 1;
      else if ( jacks_Record > Jills_Record)
         Read the next Jills_Record from the file
      else
         Match processing
}
```

There is only one pass through the file and no searching.
There will be some cases the Binary search may be faster

Also it may be worth specifiying a large buffer on the BufferedReader